# Is there an event when Select-Options value is changed

Tags: abap

Is there an EVENT that triggers when a value is changed in a `SELECT-OPTIONS`? But directly when it's changed, without having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, as soon as the user enters a value and clicks somewhere else in the screen, or when a user chooses a value from the <kbd>F4</kbd> value menu.

I've try many event, like:

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN on s_carrid.
  "This trigger only when user hit "enter"

AT SELECTION-SCREEN on VALUE-REQUEST FOR s_carrid-LOW.
  "This trigger when user press F4, but nothing after selecting a value...
```

Thanks for your help

```
DATA: v_carrid type s_carr_id.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_carrid for v_carrid no INTERVALS MODIF ID br5.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no event triggered when a value is changed in a `SELECT-OPTIONS` element. Events are raised only when a function code, a menu or a button is pressed, or eventually a radio button or a checkbox.

There's no event triggered when a value is returned from the value help (<kbd>F4</kbd> function key on the input field), the input field is directly filled with the selected value.

Instead, you may define some ABAP code when <kbd>F4</kbd> or the value help button is pressed, display the search help, get the selected value and do whatever you want, like filling the input field with the value, and any other process.